# Live data display in C over HTML

Tags: c, linux, cgi, boa

I have a moderately complex C program running on Linux, and I want to show some data from structures and some strings on a HTML page for live data presentation. I do have Boa Web Server running, but I can't think how to send the data to be displayed. Would I have to use CGI?

Thanks

Comment: Add more tags if possible. There could be people that can answer your question looking for [boa]

Comment: Why do you need Web Server for that?

Comment: I don't really need the Web Server, but I want to show the data on a HTML webpage using a web browser.

Comment: Web browser can open local HTML files, and so it can poll for data in them.
Do you need exactly Web Browser to show your data, BTW?

Comment: @c-smile Yes, needs to be able to be viewed from a web browser. Thinking how I can dump the data to be put into a HTML file easily. I was thinking of showing the data and values in HTML tables for example.

Comment: @c-smile Wouldn't constantly changing the data maybe once a second, in the file, hammer the flash memory or hard drive this file resides on?

Comment: To use Sciter or Electron then. With Sciter your program can just show HTML window that you can update from your native code. Or by sending events to the script on the page.

Using Web Browser / Web Server is not an option either if you worry about flash memory - too many things happen, file cached etc.

Comment: @c-smile This is an embedded system so limited on memory and RAM. I believe those frameworks need like 10MB or more. I only have 3 MB Free of RAM and FLASH space

Comment: Finally we are getting somewhere. So your browser is not running on the same machine? If so then you have two options: poll your server from browser with some interval for the data or to use something like WebSockets so you can push data from your app to the browser connected to your server.